# What is the magical tree in this SE site's logo?

Tags: history, gentiles, symbols-symbology, trees

Finally my curiosity got the best of me, after seeing the icon for Mi Yodeya appear in the "Hot Network Questions" sidebar so many times. I joined this community just to ask:

**What is the swirly magical looking tree in the site logo of [Mi Yodeya / judaism.SE](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/)?**

[image]

I gather it must be pretty important, but it's not common knowledge to me.

Please explain it in a way someone with limited knowledge of Judaism can understand.

An answer might give an overview that touches on, for example:

- What is the tree's name?
- What is it's significance?
- Are there some notable stories involving it that curious people should know about?
- Is it related to the Kabbalah / Tree of Life?

Links to explore specific aspects in further detail are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: This is probably a better question for the meta site, but one I'd like to know

Comment: @PaulWalker I was on the fence considering whether to post here or on the meta, but I feel like all the *answers* will be pertaining to Judaism more than the SE Network or site design/functionality/moderation sorts of topics.

Comment: They might let it stay where it is. But I meant on this meta site:   https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This was asked on [meta] here https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5528/759

Comment: Note that the answer to the above-linked Meta question quotes the guy who designed the tree logo. So it's about as definitive as you can get.